# Cannot send the input correctly in AHK

Tags: script, automation, autohotkey

I try to send the input of a file name in the AHK script but I cannot get the right input. The AHK is not sending the whole text that I want it to send.
Here is my code.

```
SendInput, 867_CCM.xls
```

But AHK only sends **CCM.xls**

Please let me know what mistake I am making.

Answer (score 1):

Try `SendInput,{Raw}867_CCM.xls`

> **{Raw}**
>
> [v1.0.43+] Sends the keystrokes exactly as they appear rather
> than translating {Enter} to an ENTER keystroke, ^c to Control-C, etc.
> Although the string {Raw} need not occur at the beginning of the
> string, once specified, it stays in effect for the remainder of the
> string.